# Data definition has no type or storage class

Tags: c, pointers, struct, malloc, typedef

I tried to allocate storage to a struct pointer. Here is the abreviated code - could you tell me what did I do wrong?

can.h

```
#ifndef CAN_H_
#define CAN_H_

typedef struct {
  u32  id;
  u32  mask;
  char length;
  char data[8];
  char status; 
} CAN_PACKET;
```

project.c

```
#include "can.h"

CAN_PACKET *packet_Tx, *packet_Rx;
CAN_PACKET packet1, packet2;
packet_Tx = (CAN_PACKET*)malloc(sizeof(CAN_PACKET));      /* line 20 in text */
packet_Tx = &packet1; 
packet_Rx = &packet2;

int main(void)
{
  while(1)
  {
        }
}
```

I get these errors/warnings:

> Warning   1   data definition has no type or storage class    c:\users\blu\documents\avrstudio\Can5\Can5\Can5.c   20  2   Can5
>
> Warning   2   type defaults to 'int' in declaration of 'packet_Tx'    c:\users\blu\documents\avrstudio\Can5\Can5\Can5.c   20  2   Can5
>
> Error 3   conflicting types for 'packet_Tx'   c:\users\blu\documents\avrstudio\Can5\Can5\Can5.c   20  2   Can5
>
> Error 4   previous declaration of 'packet_Tx' was here    c:\users\blu\documents\avrstudio\Can5\Can5\Can5.c   18  13  Can5
>
> Warning   5   initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast    c:\users\blu\documents\avrstudio\Can5\Can5\Can5.c   20  14  Can5

The rest of the code complies fine when the packet_Tx assignment lines are commented out. Thanks a lot guys.

Comment: What didn't work? How can you tell? What did you do with packet_pt later?

Comment: Your example is 100% correct, so "didn't work" is a bit vague...  Please don't typecast the return value of the `malloc()` call in C, though.

Comment: The complier constantly complains about conflict types for "packet_pt". If I comment out the packet_pt assignment lines, the code complies without error. That's why I am a bit confused.

Comment: You don't "allocate storage to a pointer". Rather, you allocate storage, and you have a pointer pointing to that storage. The pointer itself is already stored somewhere.

Comment: Following I am showing the error message from compiler... Warning 1:data definition has no type or storage class..... Warning 2:type defaults to 'int' in declaration of 'packet_pt'... Error 3:conflicting types for 'packet_pt'.... Error 4 previous declaration of 'packet_pt' was here.... Warning 5:initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast.... Error 6:initializer element is not constant...... All above comments are referred to the 1st assignment statement, except comment 4 is referred to pointer declaration statement..I am quite puzzled.

Comment: Where does your "previous declaration of packet_pt was here" point to? That is probably your problem.

Comment: Actually Error 4 refers to the line "DATA_PACKET* packet_pt;", any ideas?

Comment: Can you copy and paste the first 6 compiler messages into the question please (including line numbers)? Also, can you then add the line numbers to your question, and ensure that you haven't mistyped anything in the code snippet you've already posted (eg swapped a `,` for a ';' after `packet1`)

Comment: Ok, if you don't mind me dumping my code:) Thanks

Comment: @greywolf274 dumping your whole code is discouraged, but a copy and paste of the relevant bits (and error messages) is definitely encouraged. Note that the bits that you've posted so far compile fine - the error is either somewhere else in your source, or you didn't copy/paste from your source :)

Comment: I see, could it be that I didn't put the pointer assignment in main(), as I did in earlier code. My bad....

Answer (score 10):

In C, you can't have code outside functions. Move these two lines:

```
packet_Tx = (CAN_PACKET*)malloc(sizeof(CAN_PACKET));  
packet_Tx = &packet1; packet_Rx = &packet2;
```

To the top of the `main()` method:

```
int main(void)
{
   packet_Tx = (CAN_PACKET*)malloc(sizeof(CAN_PACKET));  
   packet_Tx = &packet1; packet_Rx = &packet2;
```

Comment: I checked again, just to make sure there is only one packet_pt in main()... any other ideas? Thanks

Comment: @greywolf274 we'll need more information - see my comment on your question. Also, did you copy and paste the code snippets, or write them out again? If you wrote them out again, be careful that you haven't accidentally corrected whatever the mistake was when asking the question ;)

Comment: It worked, I was too eager to put that packet as global variable, I was even assigning the storage to them outside of main().. Thanks a lot.. funny, I did correct my mistake as I wrote the code in my question...haha... Thanks again..